# What is Drupal Panel Node Template

Tags: drupal, templates, panel

What is Drupal Panel Node Template and how can i use it to create a page based on person type node.

Also is there any tutorial on creating pages using Panel Node Template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need to use a node panel. What you want to do is edit the node template for the content type you want to customize instead.
There is extensive documentation in http://drupal.org/project/panels